# Controller returns JSON containing two entities instead of one

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-restcontroller

Here is my controller:

```
 // CREATE NEW TODOITEM FROM SENT JSON
@PostMapping("/todos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ToDoItem newToDo(
        @RequestBody ToDoItem toDoItem,
        Principal principal
) {
    User currentUser = userService.findLoggedInUser(principal);
    return toDoItemService.addToDo(toDoItem, currentUser);
}
```

**toDoItemService.addToDo**:

```
public ToDoItem addToDo(ToDoItem toDoItem, User user) {
    String toDoTitle = toDoItem.getTitle();
    LocalDate toDoDueDate = toDoItem.getDueDate();
    ToDoItem newToDo = new ToDoItem(user, toDoTitle, toDoDueDate);
    return toDoItemRepository.save(newToDo);
}
```

**ToDoItem entity** (ommited constructors and getters/setters):

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TO_DO_ITEMS")
public class ToDoItem extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(name = "COMPLETED")
private boolean completed;

@Column(name = "DUE_DATE", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate dueDate;

// a ToDoItem is only associated with one user
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

And my **toDoItemRepository** just extends CrudRepository.

When I shoot:

```
{
"title":"testtodo3",
"dueDate": [
    2015,
    12,
    6
]
}
```

at `localhost:8080/todos` I get this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "testtodo3",
"completed": false,
"dueDate": [
 2015,
 12,
 6
],
"user": {
"id": 1,
"username": "gruchacz",
"password": "password",
"email": "newUser@example.com"
}
}
```

Why are all the details of my User visible when I'm returning only ToDoItem (as save from CrudRepository does)? I know my ToDoItem is linked to User, but i would like it to return only ID, title, completed and dueDate WITHOUT user data? I know I could override toString method in ToDoItem entity and return a String from that controller but it's very unelegant and would prefer to retunr just ToDoItem and jackson to handle conversion to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for you:

1: add @JsonIgnore on User field in `ToDoItem`, Jackson will ignore it, or

2: Use `DTO` pattern, create another value object to deliver it back on HTTP layer.

I will recommend second option